# How to escape the parameter symbol in ADO.NET

Tags: ado.net

We're using ADO.NET with parameterized queries with SQL Server using the DBCommand object, so the parameter symbol is `@`, and things have been working fine.  However we now have a query where `@` is part of the hard coded data.  By default ADO.NET thinks it IS a parameter and the whole thing goes pear shaped.

Is there a way to escape the `@` in this one case so it's just treated as part of the data?  I tried `\@` but that didn't work either.

Comment: Can you give an example of the command string

Comment: I can't give the exact example, but if you did something like command.text = "SELECT * from users email_address = 'test@example.com'" where the data is hardcoded.  If you try to use this DBCommand with a DataAdapter to fill a DataSet, you don't get an error but you get a really unexpected result: the DataTable in the DataSet was empty and I mean completely empty, not even column definitions!  So it's not like the query return 0 records, the whole process got derailed somewhere.  If we remove the `@` then we get schema and column definitions but 0 records (which is fine).